# issue with adapterview and addview

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

so I'm trying to build and android app which takes in code from user input and puts it into a custom layout for a listview.

Here is the xml for the layout i have for each element of the list (the following is called game_row.xml)

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team1out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dateout"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team2out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/team1out"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score1out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/team2out"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score2out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/team2out"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/team2out"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the java code for my class:

```
public class KeepScoreHomeScreen extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Game> Game_data = new ArrayList<Game>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            System.out.println("this shouldnt happen");
            ArrayList<Game> inp = (ArrayList<Game>) savedInstanceState.get("games");
            System.out.println("game made");
            Game_data.addAll(inp);

        }
        // System.out.println("helo");
        // Game_data.add(new Game(1,2,3,4,3, "t","T"));

        GameAdapter adapter = new GameAdapter(this, R.layout.game_row, Game_data);

        // This is used to update the maximum number of days in a month

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        ListView gameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);
        gameList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("games", Game_data);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_newEntry:
            toNewEntry(this.findViewById(R.layout.home_screen));
            break;
        case R.id.action_help:
            buildHelp(this.findViewById(R.layout.home_screen));
            break;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            buildSettings(this.findViewById(R.layout.home_screen));
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void toNewEntry(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, KeepScoreActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int r, int j, Intent intent) {
        // System.out.println("hedslo");
        Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("myfirstintent");
        int sc1 = bundle.getInt("score1");
        int sc2 = bundle.getInt("score2");
        int ye = bundle.getInt("year");
        int mo = bundle.getInt("month");
        int da = bundle.getInt("day");
        String te1 = bundle.getString("team1");
        String te2 = bundle.getString("team2");
        Game g = new Game(sc1, sc2, ye, mo, da, te1, te2);
        Game_data.add(g);
        GameAdapter adapter = new GameAdapter(this, R.layout.game_row, Game_data);
        ListView gameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);
        gameList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void buildHelp(View view) {
        /***
         * this code to build an alert dialog was taken from
         * http://stackoverflow
         * .com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view
         * 
         * I used this code because it allowed me to insert a simple xml file as
         * my alertdialog
         * 
         */

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.help_layout, (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialoglayout);
        builder.show();
    }

    public void buildSettings(View view) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_layout, (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialoglayout);
        builder.show();

    }
}
```

The problem I have is that every time I manage to create the game_row outputs and then attempt to inflate the setting bar I get hte following error

```
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:477)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:497)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at edu.ucsb.cs.cs185.hw4skeleton.KeepScoreHomeScreen.buildSettings(KeepScoreHomeScreen.java:145)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at edu.ucsb.cs.cs185.hw4skeleton.KeepScoreHomeScreen.onOptionsItemSelected(KeepScoreHomeScreen.java:91)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2534)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:958)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:514)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:99)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-10 14:27:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
```

can anyone please help me figure out how to get my views to play nicely with eachother?

Comment: The `View` you're trying to inflate is not one that is supported by `AdapterView`.  Have you tried using a different type of `View`?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 interesting... I tried changing the view to an adapterview and it crashed on startup, what type of view would be supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `LayoutInflater` improperly.  In the following block of code...

```
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_layout, (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus());
```

...the inflater attempts to do two things:

1. Inflate the XML layout using the supplied ViewGroup to determine root LayoutParams
2. Attach the inflated layout to the supplied ViewGroup

You don't want the second thing to happen because you are handing the view off to an AlertDialog, not attaching it to the "current focus" (which is apparently a ListView in your crash log).  You also don't want the first thing to happen as written because the "current focus" won't be the parent of this inflated view so using it to figure out LayoutParams is pointless as well.

Normally, you should **always** pass the direct parent view you are going to attach to as the second parameter of `inflate()`, and then use the third parameter if you don't want to attach the two at that time.  However, in this example you have no access to the actual parent view (which is inside the AlertDialog being built) and it will override any `LayoutParams` anyway, so you should modify your code to not pass a parent while inflating:

```
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_layout, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
```

**SIDE NOTE:**

Again, this is only for this particular case.  In almost **every** other circumstance you should use `inflate()` like this:

`inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_layout, parent, false);`

Where you pass in the real parent view of the inflated layout.

Comment: Thank you that worked! Interesting... so I just want to make sure i understand what's going on... because this is an alert dialog, it would change the layoutparams in a way that would be detrimental to the listview. So we dont give it the parent view because we want it to have its own individual layout params?

Comment: You are inflating a new layout to attach to an `AlertDialog`.  Any `ListView` in your application has no relevance to that discussion so it shouldn't be considered at all in this block of code.  The additional point I was making was that in normal circumstance you should pass the parent view to `inflate()`, but in the case of a dialog you don't have the right view to pass in.